# Voting system question

Tags: php, html

I have a voting system for posts users make where other users can like/dislike

currently is displaying one number. This number is if a user likes, goes to '1' if they dislike goes back down to '0'

I want it to display how many like it has and a seperate number for how many dislikes it has
I believe my current score code is this...

```
$net_vote = $row['votes_up'] - $row['votes_down']; //this is the net result of voting up and voting down
```

Is this correct? How can i make it so it displays both scores? one for 'like' one for 'dislike'

Comment: You "believe your current score code" is that? Do you not have access to your own score code?

Comment: Im very new to php.. i took a tutorial and adapted it for my own use. Everything is working to how i need other than the showing votes and i cant get my head round it (as im very new). I do not need to be critised on my coding abilities as everyone has to start somewhere and learn. Im just looking from some help

Comment: Fair enough, apologies if I was being hurtful. In general, we appreciate it if you show us what you've tried and if you make a concise example to illustrate where your problem or question is. People will be much more willing to solve a specific problem than to design a comprehensive package for you.

Answer (score 2):

Will display only votes up (likes)

```
echo 'Likes: '.$row['votes_up'].'<br />';
```

Will display only votes down (dislikes)

```
echo 'Dislikes: '.$row['votes_down'].'<br />';
```

And your current code is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this will work:

```
echo "Votes up: " . $row['votes_up'] . "<br />";
echo "Votes down: " . $row['votes_down'] . "<br />";
```

Comment: is it possible to add a cookie to allow users to only vote once ?

Comment: it is. However, it is easy to just clear cookies from browser cache. Keeping this information in a database would be a better option. Though using cookies for learning purpose could be useful.

Comment: What is it called where i use a DB to do this then? Il give it a quick google search

Comment: Well, you need to learn about forms and form processing in php, insert/update statements in mysql. http://www.tizag.com has easy to understand tutorials, and very many of them. You can learn the basics there. Just keep in mind those are quite old :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is some database call before hand that assigns `$row` as an associative array for the Post in question, using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Anyway it should be as simple as:

```
<p>Current Score: <?php echo $net_vote ?><br />
Likes: <?php echo $row['votes_up'] ?> | Dislikes: <?php echo $row['votes_down'] ?> </p>
```

The code looks ok, not sure if I thought the problem was simpler if so let me know.